# output appears without statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am beginner in JS. i know a little about console.log(). As i know we use `console.log()` to print something. here i am facing a problem in code but can not get it.the problem is given below

```
   var understand = true;
   while( understand )
    {
      console.log("I'm learning while loops!");
      understand = false;
    }
```

i use only once console.log() but here two output appears :

```
1. I'm learning while loops!
2. false
```

my question is why it prints `false`. i don't use any statement to print `false` so how could it appears and why..?? requesting to help me to figure out the problem. Thank you

Comment: Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/claustrofob/sCzse/ . It does't output `false`. Check the rest of your code.

Comment: This happens only on your console. it's printing the value of `understand` variable. As a script executed inside a document you won't see that value

Comment: Do you test this in the chrome console or nodejs cmd? They will output the stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're trying out that code actually in the console? If so you'll notice that as you enter individual statements the console prints whatever the expression evaluates to.

`understand = false` both sets the value of that variable and evaluates to `false`.

I further assume you've entered all of that into the console at once, in which case the console is going to show the result of any of your `console.log()` statements (of course) and the value of the last statement in the code block. Note that if you change it such that the last line executed does something else you will get something other than `false` output. E.g., the following:

```
var understand = true;
while( understand )
{
   console.log("I'm learning while loops!");
   understand = false;
}
var x = 1;
```

...outputs:

```
I'm learning while loops!
undefined
```

...because the `var x = 1;` statement is `undefined` if taken as an expression.

Comment: thank you so much sir. with this question i get the answer of some other unsaying question. but in addition get a negative vote from someone and failed to understand why :O .. btw thanks again , the ans is really helpful

Comment: You're welcome. The negative vote on the question might be because you didn't actually say that you were running your code in the console (as compared to on a web page, the more usual place for JS), so we had to guess that part based on the fact that the code as shown wouldn't have the output you described if run on a web page - which makes the question kind of confusing. Or it might just be because some people seem to down-vote almost randomly and never explain themselves.

Answer (score 1):

When you run this code in your console, it'll probably output false. JS consoles generally output the value of an assignment statement, like `understand = false`, will be followed by `false` in the console. 
Once you run this code from a script file, it won't log `false`

Answer (score 0):

The answer of nnnnnn should be close to the truth, but I have tried with `var x = true` added to the end of your code, it still gives `false` printed on Chrome.

Instead, if you put `x = true` after it (without `var`), it will print true, so I think it is also related to the scope of the variable. But I am not sure.
I think this question is worth to be discussed and not voted down.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code. I guess your executing the code in Developer Console. If yes, Developer Console will print the return value of the code your executing. In your case, it prints the value of `understand`.